# Changing the path for Worklight LogDirectory

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I want to change the log directory to my custom path. So i have edited the server.xml like below.

```
<logging consoleLogLevel="OFF" copySystemStreams="false" maxFileSize="5" maxFiles="5" messageFileName="messages.log" logDirectory="/var/log" />
```

But once i changed and restarted the server it is not starting and throwing the below error

```
Launching LibertyServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130510-0831) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_45-b06 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server LibertyServer has been launched.
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 806
```

Worklight version 6.0.0.2 Liberty profile version 8.5.5.0-20130510-0831

if you need any info please comment.

Comment: What is the related error in messages.log?

Comment: I don't see any error in messages.log file. Server itself not starting

Comment: Forgot to mention I have tired setting an environment variable for "LOG_DIR" but again the same result it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. it is the problem with the permission.

Please follow the below steps to avoid the errors.

1. Modify server.xml logging property like in the question.
2. Modifying value of ‘com.ibm.ws.logging.log.directory’ property in bootstrap.properties file to "/var/log"
3. Giving write permission to wladmin in folder ‘/var/log’ using the following command.

   chmod -R 777 /var/log with superuser (superuser is root)